# NReco.ImageGenerator failed to generate image from file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

i'm trying to create jpg files from html using **NReco.ImageGenerator** nuget.
i'm using function 'GenerateImageFromFile', in most cases the generation works fine, in other cases the dll throws me:
'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in NReco.ImageGenerator.dll

Additional information: Image generation failed: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError'

i'll be glad to hear your opinion, any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I have found the solution. this was caused due to missing resource in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

NReco uses an open source program called "wkhtmltopdf" (you can find it on https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf). 
After run your application the .dll puts the "wkhtmltoimage.exe" in the path, in my case when I run the "wkhtmltoimage.exe" it asks for a .dll, in the majority of the cases you just need install the Visual C++ redistributable package (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784)

Answer (score 0):

Since ImageGenerator is a .net wrapper for wkhtmltoimage you can apply the following command line option to ignore content load errors:

```
var htmlToImage = new NReco.ImageGenerator.HtmlToImageConverter();
var htmlToImage.CustomArgs = " --load-error-handling ignore ";
```

With this option wkhtmltoimage will ignore errors when referenced resource (js,css,images etc) cannot be downloaded.

Ederson's answer about VC++ runtime libs is correct for case if ImageGenerator throws an exception for any input (error message is "The pipe has been ended" or "Image generation failed: (exit code: 255)").